# Cannot load module

Tags: apache, mod-wsgi

I receive this error when I try to run Apache 2.2 with mod_wsgi, I have the correct Python version number and the module is installed correctly for Apache.

httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 128 of C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/modules/mod_wsgi.so into server: The specified module could not be found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Verify that you have the right build of Python for your Apache installation.  If you have a 32-bit Apache build and 64-bit Python build you will receive this error.  Apache only comes in 32-bit for Windows, so if you're running 64-bit make sure you still get 32-bit Python.

Answer (score 1):

The permissions on the file must be such that the daemon user that Apache runs as can read it. Also make sure that the file isn't actually called mod_wsgi.so.so due to Windows file browser hiding the outer .so extension.